# How can I get a property dynamically in a model using c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, properties, model

How can I get a property dynamicly like this in c#

```
 @LabelFor(m => m.GetType().GetProperty("Property1"))
 @LabelFor(m => m.GetType().GetProperty("Property2"))
```

Comment: What is the problem you try to solve with this construct? You need to provide more information to your question in order for people to really help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class PropOf<T>
{
    public static string Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<T, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a member expression");
        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}
```

Usage:

@LabelFor(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(PropOf<**YourModelOrClassName**>.Property(x => x.Property1)))

Comment: How is that "dynamic" - the original post implied the Property wasn't known at compile time.  If the property is known at compile time you can just do `@LabelFor(m => m.Property1)`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. However, his question is "how to get property dynamically in c#"... above usage is just a sample of using it and not addressing anything relating to razor code. Just can't able to ask him to give more details on his question as I just registered yesterday and can't post comments from the questions. :)

Comment: the real problem is that i need to create a view but i dont want to write each property.

Answer (score 0):

I wanto to change this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prop1)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Prop2)
....
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Propn)
```

to this:

```
for (var prop in {"Prop1","Prop2", ... , "Propn"})

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GetType().GetProperty(prop))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
foreach (var prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name))
}
```

didn't test it. hope it helps. :)